# jquery flexbox ?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-flexbox

I'm using right now FlexBox plugin to make search box, everything work fine but how can i make the css work perfectly with the search box ( the css file that downloaded with flexbox )

I have the following html

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">

        <div id="suggest"></div>

</form>
```

and the flexbox callback

```
$(function(){

// begin to write 
$("#suggest").flexbox('back/search.php', {
    width: 350,
    method: 'post',
    watermark: 'Enter value',
    noResultsText: 'No Value',
    maxVisibleRows: 8,
    containerClass: 'ffb',
    contentClass: 'content',
    inputClass: 'ffb-input',
    arrowClass: 'ffb-arrow'
  });

  });
```

Comment: what's wrong here? There's no way from your question to tell what is incorrect about the styling.

Comment: this is out of the question but how you use a php as a data source? are you using mysql_query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the page in Chrome. Right click and click `Inspect Element`

You need to create a CSS Stylesheet for the code that you see during `inspect element`.

Alternatively, you could use this to view what's actually in the HTML DOM when you are viewing the page.

html:

```
<textarea id="whats_in_dom"></textarea>
```

jQuery

```
$('textarea').text($('/*container holding flexbox*/').html());
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/DGDrx/