# Displaying mysql records in jQuery Flexbox plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, jquery-flexbox

```
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(function() {
$('#jo').flexbox({  
        "results": [  
            { "id": "1", "name": "002155" },  
            { "id": "2", "name": "002155" },
            { "id": "3", "name": "asdasdasd" }
        ]}, 
    {  
showArrow: false  
});
            });  
        </script>
```

This code at top is the records that will suggest by the flexbox, for example ill type **00** it has two suggestion the 002155 and 002155, but the problem is the result of the word suggested is static, i read some code coming from this site that they link a php page to be use as the database. here is the sample...

```
$("#suggest").flexbox('back/search.php', {
```

this code above is from:[jquery flexbox ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533858/jquery-flexbox) i try to make some alternative to be able to use mysql as the result of the word suggestion;

```
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(function() {
$('#jo').flexbox({  
        "results": [  
    <?php
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

        mysql_select_db("accom");
        $query = mysql_query("select * from myproject");
            while($i = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $ii++;
                print"{ id : ".$ii.", name: ".$i[per_name]." },";       
            }
    ?>
        ]}, 
    {  
showArrow: false  
});
            });  
        </script>
```

but it doesnt work ;-(, help me please, to make the source of the word suggestion is coming from a sql query, thank you guys..

by the way here is my table

```
myproject
per_id(int 100)auto_increment
per_name(varchar 100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generated json is not valid.

In fact, parameter don't include second parameter (since you close object with '}') and names values are strings, so you probably need to add quote.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function() {
            $('#jo').flexbox({  
                "results": [  
                    <?php
                        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                        mysql_select_db("accom");
                        $query = mysql_query("select * from myproject");
                        while($i = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                        {
                            $ii++;
                            print"{ id : ".$ii.", name: '".$i[per_name]."' },";       
                        }
                    ?>
                ], 
                showArrow: false  
             });
        });  
        </script>
```

Be careful, you should need to espace name values in case name contains quote characters.

Comment: how about if the mysql_query page is in seperate another page?

Comment: You can include your php script, for example:
<?php include("monscript.php"); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Best practise would be to have a php call, json get the data you need then load it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function() {
$.getJSON("search.php", function(data){
    $('#jo').flexbox({  
        "results": data, 
        showArrow: false  
    });
}); 
});  
</script>
```

Then in your search.php you do the following:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("accom");
$query = mysql_query("select * from myproject");
$data = array();
while($i = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $data[] = array('id' => $ii, 'name' => $i[per_name])       
}
echo json_encode($data); die();
```

So now when the page is done loading it calls your php search function, gets the data in json format and you just assign it to your flexbox.